# Inserting New Rows into a DataGridView when bound to a BindingSource

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, objectdatasource

I am having difficulty getting my complex object databinding to work properly. I have 3 DataGridViews on a form and 1 binding source. The BindingSource.DataSource is the FileMoveProcesses object and the DataMember is the FileMoveProcess object

```
public class FileMoveProcesses
{
    public List<FileMoveProcess> Processes { get; set; }
}

public class FileMoveProcess
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public FileMoveProcessDetails SourceDetails { get; set; }
    public FileMoveProcessDetails DestinationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

There are 2 other DataGridViews that have DataSource of the BindingSource and the DataMembers are SourceDetails and DestinationDetails respectively. This work fine if I have data already available in the xml file for these  detail items as you can see below. The edit process works just fine the updates are serialized as you would expect.

[image: Here is a pic with data loading and editable]

The problem comes in when I try to add a new FileMoveProcess. The far left DataGridView containing the FileMoveProcess will save correctly but when I attempt to add the SourceDetails and DestinationDetails data in the datagridview they fail to create the FileMoveProcessDetails  objects for the new FileMoveProcess so it's not available to write to the xml file.

[image: Data Failed to be added to the binding source]

What did I miss?

TIA

PS the ComboBoxes are Enum databinding so the data is available for the new item.

Comment: so what happens when you fill your detail grids and press save? when you debug can you see your `FileMoveProcessDetails` objects attached to the current `FileMoveProcess` or are they null?

Comment: when the Source or Destination Details grid looses focus all the entered data is cleared.

Comment: Update. I went into the DataBinding/Advanced section of the details datagrid properties and reset to binding dropdown to "none". This cleared the problem of the grid being cleared when loosing focus. Now when I click save the details objects are null.

Comment: you can have only 1 SourceDetails for FileMoveProcessDetails, right? (and 1 DestinationDetails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must add your new object to the bindingSource yourself. I created a simple version of your project, with only 2 DGV. I also set the Data Source Update Mode to "Never" in my `dataGridView2 -> DataBindings -> Advanced`

When I write a new `FileMoveProcessDetails` (in the right grid) I can save it clicking a button and calling this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myCurrentRow = dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index];
    var fmpd = myCurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
    var pp = (FileMoveProcess)processesBindingSource.Current;
    pp.SourceDetails = (FileMoveProcessDetails)fmpd;
}
```

It's very raw... but the BindingSource is saved and I don't lose my new `FileMoveProcessDetails` it when I navigate to other `FileMoveProcess` and back.

Comment: Thanks Vland. That did the trick. I assumed that the BindingSource would have taken care of that.

Answer (score 3):

I've encoutered the same problem and relized that all you have to do is to create new instance of List collecion in the default constructor. :)

```
public class FileMoveProcesses
{
    public FileMoveProcesses()
    {
        Processes = new List<FileMoveProcess>();
    }

    public List<FileMoveProcess> Processes { get; set; }
}

public class FileMoveProcess
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public FileMoveProcessDetails SourceDetails { get; set; }
    public FileMoveProcessDetails DestinationDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Going to give you a +1 for that. That is something I missed earlier on and would have helped. Thanks for the post.

Comment: You saved my day!